# How to tell if a RemoteWebDriver has quit on the other end?

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver, browserstack

I am using Selenium to run automated tests using RemoteWebDriver.  The service that I am using (BrowserStack) only allows me to run 5 sessions in parallel, and there seems to be a delay between when my code executes the driver.quit() command and when the remote session actually ends.  Is there any way I can tell programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
while(server Running) {
try {
    connect to server
    server Running
} catch(exception ex) {
    server Not Running
}
sleep for a bit
}
```

This is pseudo-code; actual code is left as an exercise for the reader. Sorry, it's Friday afternoon, and my left brain is already at the bar. :)